# Script not printing word count

Tags: python

I have a script to find the word repetition in alist:

```
newm = [u'life', u'selection', u'squire', u'naturalist', u'patriarch', u'home', u'man', u'public', u'nbsp', u'born', u'naturalist', u'theory', u'selectionbecame', u'foundation', u'country', u'gentleman', u'suggesting', u'class', u'time', u'death', u'evolutionary', u'imagery', u'ofscience', u'literature']
print newm

#count for list
counts = defaultdict(int)
print "uyti"
for x in newm:
    counts[x]+=1

print counts
```

This program does not even print "uyti". What is the error?

Comment: do you have `from collections import defaultdict` ?

Comment: did you `from collections import defaultdict`?

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Can you run python in interactive mode?

Comment: did you `from collections import defaultdict` ?

Comment: what does it print, then ?

Comment: (also, for what you do, you could use a Counter)

Comment: @njzk2 only if he is using 2.7+

Comment: @JoranBeasley : i don't know anyone still using prior versions, but yes, it is true.

Comment: 2.6 is still widely in use(and I assume plenty use even earlier versions)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
newm = [u'life', u'selection', u'squire', u'naturalist', u'patriarch', u'home', u'man', u'public', u'nbsp', u'born', u'naturalist', u'theory', u'selectionbecame', u'foundation', u'country', u'gentleman', u'suggesting', u'class', u'time', u'death', u'evolutionary', u'imagery', u'ofscience', u'literature',u'home']

#count for list

counts = defaultdict(int)

for x in newm:
   counts[x]+=1

print counts
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming python 2.5+

```
from collections import defaultdict

newm = [u'life', u'selection', u'squire', u'naturalist', u'patriarch', u'home', u'man', u'public', u'nbsp', u'born', u'naturalist', u'theory', u'selectionbecame', u'foundation', u'country', u'gentleman', u'suggesting', u'class', u'time', u'death', u'evolutionary', u'imagery', u'ofscience', u'literature']
print newm

#count for list
counts = defaultdict(int)
print "uyti"
for x in newm:
   counts[x]+=1

print counts
```

will create the defaultdict, populate it with counts and keys and do your printing (which i assume was just debugging/sanity-check stuff...)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is which words are duplicates, there is an easier way:

```
words = set(newm)
dups = [(w, newm.count(w)) for w in words if newm.count(w) > 1]
print dups
```

This will give you `[(u'home', 2), (u'naturalist', 2)]`. To find out the count for all the words, simply remove the if statement from the list comprehension.